# Trim space in <list>string C#

Tags: c#

I am working on an application where I have multiple ID in a string that I passed from my view separated by a `';'`.
So this is what it looks like "P171;P172".

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        hiddenIDnumber= hiddenIDnumber.Trim();
        List<string> listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber.Split(';').ToList();

        foreach (string str in listStrLineElements)
```

The problem is, when I split my hiddenIDnumber, even if I have two numbers, I get a count of 3 and `""` is returned (which I believe is an empty space). 
When I use a breakpoint i get "P171","P172" AND "".
This is causing my program to fail because of my FK constraints.

Is there a way to "overcome this and somehow "trim" the space out?

Comment: The only way you can get 3 entries returned is if you have 2 `;` in the string. Is this the case?

Comment: @DavidG as As i said when I check the breakpoint, it doest list `;` as being in the list, just `""`

Comment: I'm talking about the content of `hiddenIDnumber`

Comment: While you can use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries - better figure out why it happens. As David says, it can happen if you have 2 ";", like this: "P171;P172;"

Comment: @DavidG yes i do have 2 `;`

Comment: There we go! Now check the answers here, they will solve your problem (hint: only 1 so far has the correct code!)

Comment: @SleepParalysis `""` is not a space, it's an empty string. Based on your comment, hiddenIDnumber looks like this `"P171;P127;"` This means splitting on the `;` gives you three strings, you can use the code below, or simply trim off the trailing semicolon, so when it splits it won't even find the empty entry, as in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use another overload of [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) whih allows you to ignore empty entries. For example:

```
List<string> listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber
    .Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I was surprised so many people got it wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that one way to do this would be to use String Split Options. With String.Split there is an overload that takes two arguments, i.e. it would be like

```
myString.Split(new [] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This should prevent any entries in your array that would only be an empty string.

Comment: No such overload of Split method

Comment: Which language are you checking? My source is the MSDN for C# located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And what do you see down the link? :)

Comment: @Richard better to always check if your code compiles before posting, even in such trivial cases.

Comment: Closer! But now it won't compile :)

Comment: That is not an array. That might be an array initializer in certain circumstances. Code will not compile

Comment: Should work now, I made sure it compiles and all that good stuff! Thanks for checking on it everybody.

Comment: Well done for sticking with it and fixing your code. Many people just get angry at being corrected.

Comment: Haha I'm not going to leave bad code out there for other people to see! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber.Split(new char[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Use the parameter `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to automatically remove empty entries from the result list.

Comment: No such overload of Split method

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
IList<string> listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I prefer this over `new [] { ';' }` for readability, and return it to an interface (`IList<string>`).

Answer (score 0):

You will end up with the number of `;`s plus one when you split. Since your comment mentions you have 2 `;`s, you will get 3 in your list: before the first semicolon, between the first and the second, and after the second. You are not getting an empty space, you are getting a `string.Empty` because you have nothing after the last `;`

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    hiddenIDnumber= hiddenIDnumber.Trim(";");
    List<string> listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber.Split(';').ToList();

    foreach (string str in listStrLineElements)
```

This way you get rid of the ; at the end before you split, and you don't get an empty string back.